# Creating new array based off previous array getting top values

Tags: arrays

I have an array in Jupyter. I want to create two new arrays, one with the top 30% of values from the original array and one with the bottom 30% of values from the original array. Please help!

Comment: Please add some code example of what you have tried and did not manage to achieve so that people can better understand your problem and try to help

Answer (score 0):

In Python you do it like this:

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
len_pct = int(len(X) * 0.3)

first, last = X[0:len_pct], X[len(X)-len_pct:len(X)]

print(first); # [1,2,3]
print(last); # [8,9,10]
```

Live demo [here](https://repl.it/repls/SaddlebrownLowLightweightprocess)